# How to get a document's ID from Firestore document Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, document

this my code, been trying to figure it out for days and I'm basically wanting to get a specific document's ID without knowing what it is. When I copy and paste the document ID into my code it works and my data updates but what about when I don't know the document's ID. Please help! New to coding :)

I've tried all sorts of things but the firebase documentation is confusing and doesn't include Flutter documentation sadly.

```
       enum DegreeType { undergraduate, undergraduateintegrated, masters }
DocumentReference docRef =  Firestore.instance.collection('User').document();



class FirestoreID {
 String myId = docRef.documentID;
  FirestoreID({this.myId});
}



class SelectDegreeTypeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'selectdegreetypescreen';
  @override
  _SelectDegreeTypeScreenState createState() => _SelectDegreeTypeScreenState();
}

class _SelectDegreeTypeScreenState extends State<SelectDegreeTypeScreen> {

  DegreeType degreeType = DegreeType.undergraduate;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  FirestoreID id;




  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        String uid = user.uid;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
        print(loggedInUser.uid);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right:20, bottom: 50),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TopBarBackArrow(),
            LinearPercentIndicator(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
              animation: true,
              lineHeight: 15.0,
              animationDuration: 1000,
              percent: 0.16,
              linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
              progressColor: Color(0xFF77a3cc),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0),
              child: Text(
                'Select your degree type.',
                style: kAppText,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child:ListView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Undergraduate', style: kAppTextsmallest,),
                    leading: Radio(
                      activeColor: Color(0xFF77a3cc),
                      value: DegreeType.undergraduate,
                      groupValue: degreeType,
                      onChanged: (DegreeType value)  {
                        setState(()  {
                          degreeType = value;
                         _firestore.collection('User').document(id.myId).updateData({'degree_type': 'undergrad'});
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Undergraduate with Integrated Masters',  style: kAppTextsmallest),
                    leading: Radio(
                      activeColor: Color(0xFF77a3cc),
                      value: DegreeType.undergraduateintegrated,
                      groupValue: degreeType,
                      onChanged: (DegreeType value) {
                        setState(() {
                          degreeType = value;
                         _firestore.collection('User').document(id.myId).updateData({'degree_type': 'integrated'});
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Masters',  style: kAppTextsmallest),
                    leading: Radio(
                      activeColor: Color(0xFF77a3cc),
                      value: DegreeType.masters,
                      groupValue: degreeType,
                      onChanged: (DegreeType value) {
                        setState(() {
                          degreeType = value;
                        _firestore.collection('User').document(id.myId).updateData({'degree_type': 'masters'});
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ReusableButton(
              title: 'Next',
              colour: Color(0xff77a3cc),
              onPressed:() {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, SelectedDegreeYears.id);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You might get more answers if you help others identify where the problem might be. Where in the code above are the relevant lines of code related to your question? What did you try? What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you don''t know a document's ID, you have  to query for it using something else you know about its fields.  These are the only two ways to get information from Firestore - `get()` by ID, or query by field contents (or query the entire collection to get everything).

I suggest reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to learn about queries.  The flutter APIs are very similar to other platforms, and the API documentation for Firestore using Flutter is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore).